# Access matrix by string i and j like matrix[stringi] [stringj]

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix, multi-index, multi-level

I have this matrix:

[image]

That was generated like this:

```
    df = d = pd.DataFrame({
'users': [
     [('007', "us1", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 4)],
     [('008', "us1", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 5)],
     [('009', "us1", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 6)],
     [('007', 'us2', "us3", "time1", 'time2', 4)],
     [('008', 'us2', "us3", "time1", 'time2', 7)], 
     [('009', 'us2', "us3", "time1", 'time2', 11)], 
     [('001', 'us5', 'us1', "time1", 'time2', 0)], 
     [('008', 'us5', 'us1', "time1", 'time2', 1)], 
     [('007',"us3", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 2)],
     [('007',"us3", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 34)],
     [('009',"us3", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 67)]]
   })


df =(pd.DataFrame(df["users"].explode().tolist(),columns=["ID","USER1","USER2","TAU1","TAU2","DELAY"]).groupby(["USER1","USER2"])["ID"].agg(list).to_frame().unstack())
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
combined = df.index|df.columns
for col in combined:
    if col not in df.columns:
        df[col] = np.nan
```

And I want to generate a matrix of it, so I did:

```
n = 4
f = df.shape[1] // n
df = df.values.reshape(-1, f, n).swapaxes(1, 0).reshape(-1, n)
```

And now I would like to access like this: `df['us1']['us2']` but this do not work, just with numerical index, like `df[0][1]`, that do not attend my needs. I tried to find an explanation of how to make it work but I couldn't :(

PS: Remembering that this dataset is an example and on the original one I have way more users.

Comment: try `df.at['us1','us2']`

Comment: no :(, AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'at'

Comment: Ah ok, got it, before the reshape it works! Can you send the part of the doc about this? :)

Comment: and @Mike67 do you know how can I get all the column of us1, I thought it should be something like  df.at[:, 'us1'] but this does not work

Comment: Before the reshape, you can use `df['us1']`,